# Sql Query use Regex

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, regex

I have a query

```
select  de
from [KDashboard].[dbo].[EmailsRecebidos]
```

that returns "Francisco Carvalho"

so I want to get the email in a variable...
i try this:

```
DECLARE @NumStr varchar(1000)
select  de
from [KDashboard].[dbo].[EmailsRecebidos]
set @NumStr = dbo.Regex_Replace(De,'<[%-z]*>','<[%-z]*>',null )
```

but not working ... of the following error:

"Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.Regex_Replace", or the name is ambiguous."

can someone help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you defined the user-defined function? MySQL has no native way to do a regex replacement (unless you're not working with MySQL and you tagged the question incorrectly)

Comment: This is Mysql or sql-server? you should take on or another tag off

Comment: Resolve:)
select substring(De,charindex('<',de),charindex('>',de)-charindex('<',de)) as result
from [KDashboard].[dbo].[EmailsRecebidos]

Comment: There is no native regex in SQL Server.  If you need to ask this question again, you should define or reference what your UDF regex function is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
select  @NumStr = dbo.Regex_Replace(De,'<[%-z]*>','<[%-z]*>',null )
from [KDashboard].[dbo].[EmailsRecebidos]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  de
from [KDashboard].[dbo].[EmailsRecebidos]
```

Your query could return multiple rows. If you just want one row...

```
DECLARE @NumStr varchar(1000)
SET @NumStr = (SELECT top 1 dbo.Regex_Replace(De,'<[%-z]*>','<[%-z]*>',null ) from 
[KDashboard].[dbo].[EmailsRecebidos])
SELECT @NumStr
```

Or if you're trying to use the function on all rows...

```
SELECT dbo.Regex_Replace(De,'<[%-z]*>','<[%-z]*>',null ) from 
[KDashboard].[dbo].[EmailsRecebidos]
```

Comment: Assuming the dbo.Regex_Replace function you're trying to use actually exists.